# Expo push notifications - Error: Couldn’t get GCM token for device

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification, notifications, expo

i try to implement Expo Notification on mt app,
very wired, in my last expo app it work well but now it’s doesn’t,
maybe because the versions update
this is show when i try the code from expo documentation

```
Error: Couldn't get GCM token for device
```

and this is the pacage.json:

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "blabla",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.5",
    "jest-expo": "~27.0.0",
    "react-native-scripts": "1.14.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.3.1"
  },
  "main": "./node_modules/react-native-scripts/build/bin/crna-entry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native-scripts start",
    "eject": "react-native-scripts eject",
    "android": "react-native-scripts android",
    "ios": "react-native-scripts ios",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "es6-symbol": "^3.1.1",
    "expo": "^29.0.0",
    "firebase": "^5.4.1",
    "mobx": "^4.3.1",
    "mobx-react": "^5.1.0",
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "~0.55.2",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-ionicons": "^0.2.2",
    "react-native-progress": "^3.5.0",
    "react-native-simple-toast": "0.0.8",
    "react-navigation": "^2.11.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Make sure you're logged Expo. I improved when I logged in again. expo.io username and password. exp login

Answer (score 3):

Just fixed it by using **expo start** instead of **react-natives-scripts start**. 
If u get **expo-cli** error, run **npm install expo-cli --global**.

You can find more discussion related to this error [here](https://forums.expo.io/t/im-getting-push-notification-problems-error-couldnt-get-gcm-token-for-device/12200/16)